# Flex 4.5 - How do you strip tags?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex4.5

How do you strip (HTML) tags from a String in Flex 4.5 / 4.6?

Comment: User Regex!  Google it http://www.google.com/search?q=Strip+HTML+Tags+out+of+a+String+Regex&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a Then you just have to convert the Regex to ActionScript.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797139/use-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags-in-flex-as3

Comment: @JamesTomasino actually a different regex was provided below than the link you mentioned.

Comment: 4.6 pre-release is out there somewhere and will be coming out shortly in public

Comment: also @JamesTomasino the example you linked seems to only work for div's and not &lt;b&gt; and others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's an inbuilt function to strip the tags like in php.

However, you could use a regular expression to remove all text between `<` and `>`

```
var r:RegExp=/<\/??.*?\/??>/g;
```

I gotta run now, but if you could follow my line of thought:

While the string tests positive for the regexp, replace the occurrence with an empty string

That should remove all occurrences of this type:

```
<tag>
<tag />
</tag>
```

**EDIT**

```
var h:String="<html><head><title>Hello World</title></head><body><h1>Hello</h1>Hey there, what's new?</body></html>";
var r:RegExp=/<\/??.*?\/??>/s; //s=dotall to match . to newline also


while(r.test(h)) {
    h=h.replace(r, ""); //Remember, strings are immutable, so you h.replace will not change the value of h, so you need to reassign the return to h
}

trace(h);
```

OUTPUT:

> Hello WorldHelloHey there, what's new?

Comment: This actually returns a null string... `stringToParse.replace(r,"")` ... how do you have it just strip tags and not strip everything?

Comment: Try escaping the `<` and `>`, will ya?

Comment: I must be going insane, but by escaping the brackets do you mean: `var r:RegExp=/\<\/??.*?\/??\>/g;`

Comment: No I hadn't. As I wrote in my answer, I `needed to run`, so I couldn't test my code and write a complete answer

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about, it works perfectly for me. I've edited my answer, check it out

Comment: It worked with the while loop. Did not know you had to loop through - to match all.

Comment: ah, you see, replace matches only once, so you need to replace multiple times